# How to increase hangfire job timeout

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I have a .net core application which has hangfire 1.7.2 running.

So I have this job, which executes SQL stored procedure and its a long running task, can be of 30 minutes.

This gives me following error:
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been terminated.

```
services.AddHangfire(configuration => 

configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"), 
new SqlServerStorageOptions
    {
        SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
        UsePageLocksOnDequeue = false,
        DisableGlobalLocks = false
    }));
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this by increasing **SQLCommand** timeout which is by default 30 seconds.

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
 {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600; // 1 hour
        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `CommandTimeout` property on `SqlServerStorageOptions` should be what you are looking for.

Increase this to be more than 30 minutes and your jobs will stop timing out.

(See source https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/cf7bb08d24ee4953926b7717461bf8a23d895eb4/src/Hangfire.SqlServer/SqlServerConnection.cs)

Comment: I tried this answer but it was still the giving me same error, then I debugged it more and got to know that my SqlCommand was failing. It has its own CommandTimeout which is by default 30 secs. Your answer helped me debug more, thank you.

Comment: Glad i could be of some help!